# Solr URL with '#' causing issue in multicore

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

Why does Solr url has a '#' as part of its url? There were quite a few posts about the same question in the past eg. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Curious-why-Solr-Jetty-URL-has-a-sign-td4069434.html but with no proper workaround.

I never had any problem when I was just using a single core but when I made my Solr as a multicore that is when I have issues with Solr url having '#' (pound sign).

For eg.,

```
solr url - http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

(when the above solr admin url loads in a browser, it changes to this - `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/)`

When I click on individual collections to get their url, this is what I get as seen below -

```
solr url for collection1 (core 1)- http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1
solr url for collection2 (core 2)- http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection2
```

I have two different applications which should query their own particular solr collection, which means I have to provide their collection specific solr url. When I added this url `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1`, the application that should utilize solr collection 'collection1' is unable to connect to solr. It is returning '**Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server HTTP code=404 Not Found**'. Same is the case with other application using Solr 'collection2'

Please tell me how I can get rid of '#' from the solr url or any possible fix for the above issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The # is the url generated by the admin dashboard. For actually interacting with a collection, the url format is unchanged, just remove the # --

localhost:8983/solr/collection1

or /select or /update or whatever.

Comment: Hi Mike. I tried that, it gives me HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/collection1. Reason:

    Not Found

Comment: the collection name by itself will give you 404. You need to give it the rest of the url. /solr/collection1/admin/ or /solr/collection1/select/?q=*:* will work.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your above comment helped me get through the url without #. Could you please tell me what solr url should I specify in an application to query only a specific collection or core?

Comment: /solr/collection1/select/?q=your-query-goes here.